# How to refer a background-image in a div's style attribution?

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Rest Api **http://localhost:8091/zine/admin/index** leads to this page **src\main\resources\templates\admin\index.html**.

Here is the code in **Thymeleaf** , **admin/index.html**:

```
<div class="card__header card__header--img" style="background-image: url("@{/admin/demo/img/note.png}"); height: 250px;"></div>
```

Resources folders:
[image: note.png]

It's absolute path which you can see : **src\main\resources\static\admin\demo\img\note.png**

But seems won't work with this code :

```
style="background-image: url("@{/admin/demo/img/note.png}"); height: 250px;"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Good Now.

```
<div class="card__header card__header--img" th:style="'background-image:url('+@{/admin/demo/img/note.png}+'); height: 250px;'"></div>
```

A warning came out:[image]

Just ignore it.

Probably someone has even better solution, please share.